# How do I create a file to return the HTTP response 200 OK

Tags: http, server

I'm using PayPal on my site. I've moved from Drupal to Wordpress. There is a problem with the PayPal Instant Payment Notification system from old subscribers.
I have been told:
"You can put an empty file which returns the HTTP response 200 OK"
I know where the file needs to go but I have no clue how to write the contents of the file. Can anyone help?

Comment: It doesn't need to have contents to provide the response, (hint, 'empty' file fine as specified in directions)

Comment: I don't understand. I have a folder - IPNHandler ,
I put an index.html into it
What needs to be in the index.html file to make it return 200 OK ?

Comment: You don't need to do anything. As long as browser can access the `index.html` file successfully, it will get a `200 OK` response.